# Not able to add .containerRelativeFrame in my SwiftUI code

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

When I'm trying to add .containerRelativeFrame in my SwiftUI code but getting errors :

Like this, I'm getting errors :

1. Value of type 'some View' has no member 'containerRelativeFrame'
2. Reference to member 'horizontal' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
3. Reference to member 'vertical' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

--How to resolve this--

[This is the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2OQR.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please always post code as text, not image. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

This API is only available starting from iOS 17.

1. Make sure you use latest Xcode (Xcode 15).
2. Add `@available(iOS 17, *)` above your struct definition:

```swift
@available(iOS 17, *)
struct FeedView: View {
    ...
}
```